# Existe un objeto con el mismo nombre en la base de datos sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto..
Estoy haciendo un sistema de matricula con esta base de datos pero presento los siguiente problemas..

Gracias por su ayuda.............

```html
create database Final_algoritmo

create table Usuarios (
Users varchar (40) primary key,
Pass varchar (8) )

insert into Usuarios values ('Alex', '123')
insert into Usuarios values ('Administrador', '123')




create table Cursos(
CodCurso varchar (8) constraint PK_Cursos primary key not null,
Nombre varchar (30) not null,
Turno varchar (30) not null,
)

insert into Cursos values ('CU100', 'Lenguaje','Mañana')
insert into Cursos values ('CU101', 'Algebra Lineal', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU102', 'Matematica I','Mañana')
insert into Cursos values ('CU103', 'Matematica II', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU104', 'Calculo Vectorial','Mañana')
insert into Cursos values ('CU105', 'Historia del Arte', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU106', 'Fundamentos de Programacion','Mañana')
insert into Cursos values ('CU107', 'Algoritmos Avanzados', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU110', 'Lenguaje II', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU111', 'Diseño Logico','Mañana')
insert into Cursos values ('CU112', 'Contabilidad', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU113', 'Ofimatica para Ingenieros I', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU114', 'Ofimatica para Ingenieros II', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU108', 'Dibujo Asistido', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU115', 'Desarrollo de Sistemas I', 'Tarde')
insert into Cursos values ('CU116', 'Desarrollo de Sistemas II', 'Tarde')

create table Alumnos (
CodAlumno varchar (8) constraint PK_CodAlumno primary key  not null,
Nombres varchar (25),
Apellidos varchar (40),
CodCurso varchar (8) constraint FK1_CodCurso foreign key references Cursos (CodCurso) not null
 )

insert into Alumnos values ('AL10', 'Richard Augusto','Barrantes Lingan','CU101') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL15', 'Jose Luis','Lopez Oropeza','CU101') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL20', 'Americo Lucio','Inga Lopez','CU102') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL25', 'Amelia Rita','Socrates Panadal','CU102') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL30', 'Luisa Berta','Gonzales Alva','CU102') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL35', 'Claudio Pedro','Maritin Luceo','CU102') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL40', 'Martin','Arizaga Quispe','CU102') 
insert into Alumnos values ('AL45', 'Claudio Gustavo','Reyes Odria','CU102')
```

Me da el error:

> Mens. 1801, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 1 La base de datos
>   'Final_algoritmo' ya existe. Elija un nombre diferente para la base de
>   datos. Mens. 2714, Nivel 16, Estado 6, Línea 3 Ya hay un objeto con el
>   nombre 'Usuarios' en la base de datos

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SO. Evita poner todo el título en mayúsculas. Por otra parte, coloca el texto del mensaje de error, donde dirá supongo cuál es el objeto que dice que ya existe. Puedes [pulsar aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/228422/edit) para editar la pregunta y mejorarla. Gracias.

Comment: Cuales son los errores? .-.

Comment: Mens. 1801, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 1
La base de datos 'Final_algoritmo' ya existe. Elija un nombre diferente para la base de datos.
Mens. 2714, Nivel 16, Estado 6, Línea 3
Ya hay un objeto con el nombre 'Usuarios' en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Al crear la base de datos, luego la tienes que usar, para que las tablas sepan donde van

```
CREATE DATABASE Final_algoritmo; 
GO
USE Final_algoritmo;
GO
```

Y tras esto ya puedes crear tablas, llenarlas, etc...
Lo he probado y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.. Amigo un archivo de SQL server 2008 si abre en sql 2012 o 2014?

Comment: Lo mejor es importarlo desde el SQL Servet superior. Si tienes posibilidad de conectar los dos Servet haces una exportación y listo.  Si las respuestas son de tu agrado, acuérdate de apoyar a los que te responden, es la moral mpara seguir ayudando. Suerte

Comment: Ya lo hice amigo y nada...

Comment: Se hace con el asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server. Funciona correctamente.  Si las respuestas son de tu agrado, acuérdate de apoyar a los que te responden, es la moral mpara seguir ayudando. Suerte